# Unit strength Wiener process

Tags: noise, brownian-motion

I am not much aware of Brownian motion and/or the Wiener process. Recently I have been reading a research paper where they mention a variable $dW$ as a "unit strength Wiener process". My question is how can I find numerical values of $dW$? Does $dW$ have any relation with $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$?

It is also OK if anyone can point me to a good tutorial on Wiener processes that answers my question.

**Update**

Let $dW = W(t+dt) - W(t)$ then according to Wiener process characterization $dW \sim \mathcal{N}(0, dt)$. But what is the strength of the Wiener process is still unclear to me. More specifically what did they mean by saying $dW$ is a unit strength Wiener process?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! The Wikipedia page on the [Wiener process](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) answers your specific question about the link between the increments of $W$ and the normal distribution. And just searching online for "Wiener process" leads to a number of YouTube videos and other introductory material. Have you looked at those and, after having done so, is there still some physics concept that you'd like some help with?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The wiki page is helpful. But I still do not understand the meaning of strength of a Wiener process so I have updated my question above.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only give you an opinion: I believe that it refers to the variance $\sigma^2$, which appears in the defining normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, being $dt$, rather than some multiple of $dt$. I don't recall seeing a definition of $dW$ incorporating "strength". Clearly, in an application such as Brownian motion, the $dW$ will be multiplied by a "strength" parameter: $\sigma dW$. In principle, one *could* roll this into the definition of $dW$, but I thought that it was *always* defined as $dW\sim\mathcal{N}(0,dt)$, making the words "unit strength" redundant.

Comment: Since I haven't found a book reference to the "strength" of a Wiener process, I'll leave my previous comment here for now, and someone else might give a definitive answer with a reference.

Comment: @LonelyProf: Thank you for your reply. Your opinion makes sense to me.